# Oracle VM box and Windows Machine Network issue

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have Oracle Virtual box with Centos 7 Os image in Windows Machine.

My Windows Machine is restricted with someone of websites ( Example shopping, Games and Entertainment )

I'm not able to access above category website from Windows machine.

But in VM Centos 7 OS which i have created through Virtual box ( iso images).

there i'm able to access all this website.

Ideally i believe i shouldn't access Above Category website ?

Any Idea How can i block all this Website in VM also ?

Comment: How do you restrict those websites in Windows? With firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Check and compare DNS settings for both. Your windows box could be using a DNS that blocks those categories.